# Can not restore state of an editor in Eclipse RCP based application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am working on standalone Eclipse RCP based application. We have a custom Editor, which needs to be restored, after application was closed. I did everything as described here: http://rajakannappan.blogspot.com/2009/10/eclipse-rcp-saving-editor-state-and.html (set configurer.setSaveAndRestore(true), made my editor input persistable, created input factory and so on), but with no success. I have debugged the process of recreation of editor and could not find any clues. It seems, like there is some configuration problem of my plugin/editor, but I was not able to find any documentation regarding that.

So, does anybody know, if above-mentioned article is OK to use, or may be there is some better documentation/example? Or what should I check/debug to find a problem?

Comment: The article is fine - and as far as I can se correct. Have a look at `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/workbench.xml` in the RCP workspace. The `input` element for the `editor` element for your editor is interesting. Does it state the correct factory and associated data?

Comment: Yes, EditorInput is restored correctly. Actually, the problem is solved now. It turned out, that there was a code snippet, which was closing all opened editors, before activating perspective (for perspective switching, I assume). Thank you.